# Stream being passed as SOAP response

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, stream

I have a SOAP response that is passing back its body element as ...stream... and I've been told that this means a stream is being passed. How would I go about reading this stream? How can I find out what it is a stream of? The program receiving the stream is a WCF service.

Comment: @talnicolas in my experience, StreamReader isn't actually very useful for reading arbitrary streams...

Comment: @MarcGravell Oh ok well it was just a hint, I don't really know any C#.

Comment: Can you detail Client and Server a little more? WCF can pass streams quite transparently.

Answer (score 0):

Streams often can be only read once, so if you read the stream it will likely be consumed and you'll need to recreate it. One possible place where you could do it is in a custom message encoder which wraps the original binding encoder.

There are two `WriteMessage` methods you need to implement. In the buffered case, just delegate the call to the wrapped encoder, and you'll have the message contents. In the streamed case, you'd write the message passing a memory stream to the wrapped encoder, inspect the contents, then write the stream contents out to the stream passed as a parameter.

```
public override ArraySegment<byte> WriteMessage(Message message, int maxMessageSize, BufferManager bufferManager, int messageOffset)
{
    ArraySegment<byte> result = this.wrappedEncoder.WriteMessage(message, maxMessageSize, bufferManager, messageOffset);
    // message contents on the array segment.
    return result;
}

public override void WriteMessage(Message message, Stream stream)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    this.wrappedEncoder.WriteMessage(message, ms);
    // message contents in the memory stream
    ms.Position = 0;
    ms.CopyTo(stream);
}
```

Comment: thanks. i switched the transferMode from Streamed to Buffered instead in my Web.config, and now i can see the body in my logs